# How to know if asynchronous calls are finished? (HackerNews Comments)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, promise

I am building a hackernews clone on React/Redux.

Inside the component, Item.js I call `this.props.fetchItem(this.props.match.params.id);`

Here is `fetchItem` action creator:

```
export const fetchItem = (id) => {
    return dispatch => {
        return axios.get(`${ROOT_API_URL}/item/${id}.json`)
            .then(response => {
                let story = response.data;
                let commentIds = response.data.kids; // Story kids
                var allComments = [];

                let fetchComments = commentIdArray => {
                    let promiseArray = [];

                    // 1. Create requests for each commentId
                    commentIdArray.forEach(commentId => {
                        promiseArray.push(axios.get(`${ROOT_API_URL}/item/${commentId}.json`));
                    })

                    // 2. Make requests to fetch all commentIds
                    axios.all(promiseArray)
                        .then(responseArray => {
                            responseArray.forEach(response => {
                                let comment = response.data;
                                allComments.push(comment);

                                if(comment.kids){
                                    fetchComments(comment.kids);
                                }else{
                                    return false;
                                }
                            })
                            console.log("allComments: ", allComments);
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.log("error promise.all: ", error);
                        })
                }

                fetchComments(commentIds)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                if(error.response.status === 401){
                    console.error("Unauthorized");
                }else{
                    console.error("Something went wrong!");
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Basically, it receives the id of a story and fetches comments for that story. This part also works. I got all comments in an flattened array.

Here is the problem. I have to call `fetchItemSuccess` somewhere in `fetchItem`, so that I can save the data to redux. Although, I don’t know how many comments there are and I am recursively fetching them by their subcomments.

So, how do I know I have all the comments ready and then call `fetchItemSuccess`?

a story: https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/8863.json?print=pretty

a comment: https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/8952.json?print=pretty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out.

I just need to keep track of asynchronous method calls. So, I added a count variable. If count is zero, then dispatch an action.

```
export const fetchItem = (id) => {
    return dispatch => {
        return axios.get(`${ROOT_API_URL}/item/${id}.json`)
            .then(response => {
                let story = response.data;
                let commentIds = response.data.kids; // Story kids
                var allComments = [];
                var count = 0; // <=== New Line

                let fetchComments = (commentIdArray) => {
                    let promiseArray = [];
                    count++; // <=== New Line

                    // 1. Create requests for each commentId
                    commentIdArray.forEach(commentId => {
                        promiseArray.push(axios.get(`${ROOT_API_URL}/item/${commentId}.json`));
                    })
                    // 2. Make requests to fetch all commentIds
                    axios.all(promiseArray)
                        .then(responseArray => {
                            responseArray.forEach(response => {
                                let comment = response.data;
                                allComments.push(comment);

                                if(comment.kids){
                                    fetchComments(comment.kids);
                                }else{
                                    return false;
                                }
                            })
                            count--; // <=== New Line
                            if(count === 0){ // <=== New Line
                                dispatch( fetchItemSuccess(allComments) );
                            }
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                            console.log("error promise.all: ", error);
                        })
                }

                fetchComments(commentIds);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                if(error.response.status === 401){
                    console.error("Unauthorized");
                }else{
                    console.error("Something went wrong!");
                }
            })
    }
}
```

Comment: This is still kind of a bad way to use promises. The whole point of promises is to facilitate chaining. Your hack works, but it's a pretty crazy way to do this.

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn't able to refactor the code for chaining. But I'll think about a better way.

Comment: cyonder: I updated my answer with a suggestion that does what you want, and does not need reference counting.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of how your source might be structured a bit saner:

```
const fetchComments = function(commentIdArray) {
  const promiseArray = [];

  // 1. Create requests for each commentId
  commentIdArray.forEach(commentId => {
    promiseArray.push(axios.get(`${ROOT_API_URL}/item/${commentId}.json`));
  });

  let parentCommentsComments = [];

  return axois.all(promiseArray).then(responseArray => {

    responseArray.forEach(response => {

      const comment = response.data;
      parentComments.push(comment);
      if (comment.kids) {
        return fetchComments(comment.kids);
      } else {
        return [];
      }
    });

  }).then(kidsComments => {

    return parentComments.concat(kidsComments); 

  });

});

export const fetchItem = (id) => {
  return dispatch => {
    return axios.get(`${ROOT_API_URL}/item/${id}.json`)
      .then(response => {
        const story = response.data;
        const commentIds = response.data.kids; // Story kids

        return fetchComments(commentIds);

      })
      .then(comments => {

        // do something with comments?

      })
      .catch(error => {
         if(error.response.status === 401){
           console.error("Unauthorized");
         }else{
           console.error("Something went wrong!");
        }
     })
  }
}
```

Comment: In that code, where ever I call `fetchItemSuccess`, it's gonna be called multiple times. Did you realize recursive function? Edited the question.

Comment: Alright, I think one of the biggest mistakes you are making is a misunderstanding of chaining Promises. Do you think you can refactor your source to use chaining? Once you do that, either the solution will present itself, or we have a much cleaner source to solve the problem from.

Comment: It seems to be working. Although, `kidsComments` are undefined. That's why output is wrong.

Comment: Weird! I'm not sure what I'm missing then!